# Pushing objects into array using forEach

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have an on click event that changes the values of three elements that I want to combine into a json-like object:

```js
function generateNumbers() {
  let a = Math.random()
  let b = Math.random()
  let c = Math.random()
  console.log({
    "numbers": [
      {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}
    ]
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateNumbers()">Three Numbers</button>
```

Rather than replace `a`, `b`, and `c` I want to add another object `{"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}` with each click. Is this possible?

## Desired Output

```
{
  "numbers": [
    {
      "a": 0.795741457922079,
      "b": 0.07941685760724382,
      "c": 0.048012832026655516
    },
    {
      "a": 0.17600389141580575,
      "b": 0.4720288949307833,
      "c": 0.8079844242898715
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an initial object which contains the `numbers` property as array where you can push the newly generated object with `a`, `b` and `c` properties. Read about [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Try as the following:

```js
const data = {
   numbers: []
};

function generateNumbers() {
  let a = Math.random()
  let b = Math.random()
  let c = Math.random()
  
  data.numbers.push({"a": a, "b": b, "c": c});
  
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateNumbers()">Three Numbers</button>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable for the numbers outside of the `generateNumbers` function.

```js
const state = { numbers: [] }

function generateNumbers() {
  let a = Math.random()
  let b = Math.random()
  let c = Math.random()
  
  state.numbers.push({ a, b, c })

  console.log(state)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateNumbers()">Three Numbers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your object outside of function and push the new value set in `numbers` through `generateNumbers`

```
const data = { numbers: [] }

function generateNumbers(){
  const val = Math.random;
  data.numbers.push({ a: val(), b: val(), c: val() )})
}
```